# immutable helper updating value in object in array

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I'm trying to understand **immutable helper** in the context of what I'm trying to do. 
I'm trying to update the objects inside based on when an onChange event calls the INPUT_CHANGE action. it should add to the formData value not replace it. I tried $add but that didn't work the way I wanted it either. 
Also every time a a new input filed is changed it adds a new object with the same updated changes.

Array[index] -> input1 -> INPUT_CHANGE -> update object with key and value of input field as it changes.

```
inputs=[{key:{key:'input name', value: mew}}]
```

Array[index] -> input2 -> INPUT_CHANGE -> update object with key and value of input field as it changes.

```
 inputs=[{key:{key:'input name', value: mew}}, {key:{key:'input name', value: mew}}]
```

and so on ...

```
   const setupState = {
      count: 0,
      inputs: [{}],
    };

export default (state = setupState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE: {
      // const formDataArr = state.inputs[count];
      return update(state, {
        inputs: [{
          key: { $set: action.key },
          value: { $set: action.value },
        }],
      });
    }

    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Kind of confused as to how to use immutable helper for this ?

**UPDATE:** 
This is how the the object should look as user updates each input.

```
inputs: [
  {
    "score": {
      "key": "score",
      "value": "20....",
    },
    "hits": {
      "key": "hits",
      "value": "ss..",
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this even without immutable helpers ? ? Preferable with immutable helper as I'd like to know how they work as their docs don't exactly simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
export default (state = setupState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE: {
        // const formDataArr = state.inputs[count];
        return update(state, {
            inputs: [
            // contain origin state.inputs!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            ...state.inputs,
            {
                key: { $set: action.key },
                value: { $set: action.value },
            }],
        });
    }

    default: return state;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm getting an error "index.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined" when I do a log on action.key before the update the key is defined and there. Looks like its getting overridden by the update. any clue why ?

Comment: My inputs object looks like this after the update inputs: [{}] which looks like it failed to update and just set it back to its original state.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/immutability-helper/index.js:84
  81 | var nextValueForKey =
  82 |   type(object) === 'Map'
  83 |     ? update(object.get(key), spec[key])
> 84 |     : update(object[key], spec[key]);
  85 | if (!update.isEquals(nextValueForKey, nextObject[key]) || typeof nextValueForKey === 'undefined' && !hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
  86 |   if (nextObject === object) {
  87 |     nextObject = copy(object);

Comment: As I said when I first do a  console.log('key = ', action.key); its showing as the correct key, so its defined until it next line where the update() is called then it throws that error.

Comment: I'm trying to find a cdn version of immutable helper to add to jsfiddle so I can show you more easily. But not having much luck with that either.

Comment: I think I know whats missing that I forgot to add to my code. Which might be breaking what you did. each object in the array should use the key as the name for the object. I updated my code to show this. This could be the issue not your code but still haven't figured it all out yet. Have a look at the update in my question.